# How to arrange each word in my list in ascending order?

Tags: python, sorting

I am not able to arrange the letters of each word of a list in
ascending order using the swap algorithm. It's not working as the
letters aren't arranged in ascending fashion.

The code that I have used is as follows:

```
new_word_list = ['rudndr', 'jdkdjj', 'jdueir', 'llikdd', 'ldjdoe', 'peoods', 'hfjdgg']

ascending_list = []

for i in range(len(new_word_list)):
    new_word_list[i] = list(new_word_list[i])

for i in range(len(new_word_list)):
    for j in range(len(new_word_list[i])):
        if new_word_list[i][j-1] > new_word_list[i][j]:
            new_word_list[i][j-1], new_word_list[i][j] = new_word_list[i][j], new_word_list[i][j-1]
    ascending_list.append(new_word_list[i])
```

the result I am getting is:

> [['d', 'n', 'd', 'r', 'r', 'u'], ['j', 'd', 'j', 'j', 'd', 'k'], ['r',
> 'e', 'i', 'j', 'd', 'u'], ['i', 'k', 'd', 'd', 'l', 'l'], ['j', 'd',
> 'l', 'e', 'd', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'd', 'p', 'e', 's'], ['h', 'd', 'g',
> 'g', 'f', 'j']]

Comment: What is your expected result? Please add it to the question.

Comment: FYI Here is how to do the sorting with the built-in Python `sorted(...)` function: `print([''.join(sorted(s)) for s in ['rudndr', 'jdkdjj', 'jdueir', 'llikdd', 'ldjdoe', 'peoods', 'hfjdgg']])`

Comment: It didn't work because you're iterating over each letter of the word _only once_, which is not enough to produce a sorted word.

Comment: Also, why sort the words yourself anyway?  Just use `new_word_list[i] = sorted(list(new_word_list[i]))` in the first loop and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

https://i.imgur.com/FcOk0CZ.png

```
new_word_list = ['rudndr', 'jdkdjj', 'jdueir', 'llikdd', 'ldjdoe', 'peoods', 'hfjdgg']

ascending_list = []

for i in range(len(new_word_list)):
    new_word_list[i] = list(new_word_list[i])

for i in range(len(new_word_list)):
    for j in range(len(new_word_list[i])):
        for k in range(0, len(new_word_list[i]) - j - 1):
            if new_word_list[i][k] > new_word_list[i][k + 1]:
                new_word_list[i][k], new_word_list[i][k + 1] = new_word_list[i][k + 1], new_word_list[i][k]

    ascending_list.append(new_word_list[i])

print(ascending_list)
```